# Make user-defined feature set stops first and last in sequence using ArcGIS ModelBuilder and Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, network-analyst, route

I have about 800 stops, in 26 category groups (A to Z). Each category group represents a 'run' or 'route'. What I want my model to do is allow the user to define (by clicking on the map) a start and end location and then solve one of the routes. So when the model is run...

The dialogue box should ask the user for the Run Name and then to click two locations on the map. Then, it should somehow make the two user-selected locations the 1st and last stops in the sequence and solve the route.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to make your model interactive then have a look at the help file on the subject of FeatureSets. This will allow your user it click 2 points on the map which I guess could then feed into an Add location tool?

Comment: Yes, so I've got that part down but the issue is making those two points first and last in the route sequence. I suspect that I'll have to have two feature sets, one for the point that goes first, and one for the one that goes last. Just not sure how to get at the route sequence after it's been generated but before the route's been solved